# Passing base class paramter to method with subclass signature

Tags: java, inheritance

I have a simple heirarchy, `Base` and `Derived` have their usual meanings.

```
class Base{}
class Derived1 extends Base{}
class Derived2 extends Base{}
class Test {
    void method1() {
        Base b1 = new Derived1();
        Base b2 = new Derived2();

        call(b1);
        call(b2);
    }

    void call(Derived1 d){}
    void call(Derived2 d){}
}
```

Why does java not allow me calling `call` method with different types?

It says: `The method call(Derived1) in the type Test is not applicable for the arguments (Base)`

Can't it figure out the type at runtime and call the appropriate method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method resolution in java is static. In other words, compile time.

This has all sorts of advantages. For example, this code is correctly determined as being unrunnable and will not compile:

```
Base b3 = new Derived3();
call(b3); // does not compile in java.
// which is correct, as there is no call(Derived3) method at all.
```

More importantly, every method invocation in java code is known at write time (compile time). This means, for example, that you can CMD/CTRL+click on the method in your editor and hop right to the method that it invokes. And that is not a guess, which is what you get with more dynamic languages like python or javascript. It is unassailable fact, because that is literally what ends up in the class file.

Java DOES have dynamic dispatch: The method's 'identity' (this is a combination of the name, the parameter type(s), the return type, and the class it is in) is resolved at write (compile) time and written in the class file, but which actual implementation of that method ends up being chosen, that part is dynamic:

```
class Base {
    void foo() {
        System.out.println("base");
    }
}

class Child extends Base {
    void foo() {
        System.out.println("child");
    }
}

Base b = new Child();
b.foo(); // prints "child"
```

The 'identity' of `foo()` is looked up on the Base class, and therefore this code compiles: Base has a foo() method. But the actual implementation invoked at runtime is dynamic, and because `b` is referencing an object of type Child, ends up being Child's implementation of it.

Comment: Ok. Given that this thing does not work, now I need to redesign the thing that I was trying to refactor using design pattern :(

Comment: Move the `call` method into Base, presumably. That or a new interface which `Derived1` and `Derived2` both implement. Hard to say without way more detail.